# How to add a php file in index.html

Tags: php, jquery, html, tablet

I want to display an image.
On 'Windows Surface RT' it has to be 580px.
In every other devices it has to be 413px.

I am using this code to detect the operating system:

```
var OSName="Unknown OS";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Win")!=-1) OSName="Windows";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mac")!=-1) OSName="MacOS";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("X11")!=-1) OSName="UNIX";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Linux")!=-1) OSName="Linux";
```

But I couldn't detect the Device Type in jquery. So I used this php code.

```
//Get Device Info
$mobile = new Mobile_Detect;
$deviceType = ($mobile->isMobile() ? ($mobile->isTablet() ? 'tablet' : 'phone') : 'computer');
$scriptVersion = $mobile->getScriptVersion();
```

I don't want to change my index.html into index.php.
So is there a way to have a separate php file, and add it in the index.html head tag?

Comment: Assuming you have a valid reason for not wanting to simply rename your file .php, it IS actually possible to run PHP inside a html file but you have to modify your htacess file otherwise the page will be sent straight to browser without the PHP being parsed. Just add the following to your htacess or edit to your needs... <Files index.html>
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
</Files>

Answer (score 1):

You can include a php file as if it's a javascript file, and set the values in that.

In your HTML file...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="device-detect.php"></script>
```

In device-detect.php...

```
//Get Device Info
$mobile = new Mobile_Detect;
$deviceType = ($mobile->isMobile() ? ($mobile->isTablet() ? 'tablet' : 'phone') : 'computer');
$scriptVersion = $mobile->getScriptVersion();

echo "var scriptVersion = '$scriptVersion';";
```

Any javscript that is included or run after that will have access to the variable `scriptVersion`.

Answer (score 0):

You can not `include php file` in `html file`, but you can `load php data` to your
`html page` by using [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax) like,

```
$(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'page.php',
        success: function(data){
            $(data).appendTo('body');// data is html
        }
    });
});
```